# Proguard minifyEnabled True app not working as expected

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

Every time I've tried to turn minifyEnabled to True, it doesn't work as expected, it doesn't show any fatal errors or crashes.

minifyEnabled set to False. Working copy - 
[image: minifyEnabled set to False. Working copy]

minifyEnabled set to True. Not working - 
[image: minifyEnabled set to True. Not working]

Based on the above scenario, I couldn't figure out which methods or class the application has trouble running it.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.auth0.android.jwt.Claim;
import com.auth0.android.jwt.JWT;
import com.example.mediminder.API.ISearchAPI;
import com.example.mediminder.API.RetrofitClient;
import com.example.mediminder.R;
import com.example.mediminder.models.LoginResponse;

import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


 private void validateOTP() {
    Log.d(TAG, "validateOTP: pressed");
    Log.d(TAG, "validateOTP: token: " + token);
    String otp = etOTP.getText().toString();
    Call<LoginResponse> call = myAPI.validateotp(id, otp);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
```

Comment: Which library do you use to validate OTP?

Comment: updated on the post

Comment: Try to add those suggestion in your `proguard-rules.pro` file: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro

Answer (score 0):

If you have used any library, add the proguard rules for those specific libraries to behave as expected.